# Connecting to SQL Server 2000 with SSMS 2008

Tags: ms-access, odbc, sql-server-2000, ssms

I have been trying to solve this problem for months now and searched lots of threads, but no success.

Our office has SQL Server 2000 database, which is installed on Windows XP. I am given 'sa' password. On my computer, which is Windows 7, I have SSMS 2008. I am able to connect to mentioned server using Windows ODBC data source and with MS Access.

The problem is no matter what I tried, I could not connect with SSMS. When I go to "Server Connection" > "Server Name" >  > "Network Servers" in SSMS, the needed server is found automatically, but I still fail to connect. I know that SSMS 2008 should be able to connect to SQL Server 2000 (or maybe I am wrong?).

Please help.

Comment: As far as I remember, it won't work. You may want to consider replacing the SQL Server 2000 since it's [out of even extended support as of April 2013.](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=PN&alpha=SQL+Server+2000&Filter=FilterNO)

Comment: Wish it was up to me... Would have done long ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with help from others.

I increased the connection time-out from 15 seconds to 120sec and that did the trick